# Group items by date in a listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I would like to create groups by day for my items in a ListView (like a LongListSelector in WP7). I succeed with alphabetical items thanks to the CharacterGroupings class but I try to find the best way with timestamp. Do you have any idea to help me sorting items by creating by month/day, then put all the relating items in these groups ?

Comment: so each item has a prop `creationdate`? if so you can just write a compareTo method for the items so the get sorted by date and then walk through the list and set the groups

Comment: @SebastianL : Yes. the prop is a timestamp. So I understood I have to parse the timestamp to day and month and group them ?

Comment: there 2 ways of achieving this, check or create the right group on adding or walk through the entire list and set groups after sorting. (the first is more efficient)